# Why question on video course closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Why was https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180796/video-courses-on-powershell closed?

Comment: How is the question a conceptual question on software development?

Comment: So where would I ask this question?

Comment: I would categorize it as a "List" question, where everyone lists their favorite X that comes close to answering the question. It wouldn't fit any of the StackExchange sites because all of the answers are potentially equally valid.

Comment: Ahhh, so my question gets downvoted then closed... then my question about why gets downvoted... nice

Comment: Hi Joel, downvotes on meta don't mean anything other than someone disagrees. It doesn't affect your reputation, so don't worry about that. :)

Answer (score 6):

It was closed because 5 users thought that it didn't belong on this site and they voted to close it. Although the majority of the five users decided that it was off topic, "not constructive" would probably have been a better reason. The question exhibits several characteristics that make it unsuitable for the Stack Exchange format - it is a [list question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info), there's no criteria on which to rate answers other than personal opinion, and it focuses on requesting resources rather than sharing a combination of knowledge and experiences.